# Inserting Dynamic Data Into Cassandra Column Family

Tags: filter, cassandra, where-clause, data-modeling, cql

It might not be a relevant title for this question, but if I explain what I mean, it makes sense.

In order to learn how Cassandra works, I have the following scenario :

Consider I have an online store with lots of different products such as cars, smartphones, clothes etc. in which every product has its own specs.

I need some examples around how to model my Products column family?

It should be mentioned that I need to filter them by specs. something like:

`SELECT * FROM Products WHERE Ram > 3;`

Comment: Adhoc search queries... Cassandra is not be good choice

Comment: @undefined_variable but what I wanna do is to gather huge amount of data from other websites and represent the data in my own website. That's a lot of data that I can't store in relational databases

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra data modeling suggests one table for each query.
Now if you want to query on specs, we need to make specs as one of the keys. Using that table you can query something like this:

```
SELECT * from products where specs = 'RAM';
```

If you want to filter on brand, you need to keep brand_name as one of the columns and your query would look like this:

```
SELECT * from from products where brand_name = 'brandname';
```

So, what we are looking at here is we need to make 'RAM' as one of the columns.
You would need to do data wrangling to create data for each specs. For example: you have data with `product_id,spec,inventory`. You would need to do some analysis and see if you need to create columns for each spec or you can group a lot of specs and create new columns. The final data may look like : 
`product_id,ram` `product_id,hdd` etc. You get the idea.

If you have a lot of specs, then maybe you need to create separate table for different products and then design data model from there.

I'd suggest you take [data modeling course](https://academy.datastax.com/resources/ds220-data-modeling) for a better understanding of cassandra data modeling.

Comment: But there are lots of specs and I don't know about some of them, Is it reasonable to have a column family with hundreds of clustering keys on it?

Comment: I guess a better choice is to have a map for specs, But as I know, you can only filter key or value. Something like `SELECT * FROM Products WHERE Specs CONTAINS 'Ram' > 3;'` is not allowed! Right?

Comment: It won't work in cassandra. With complex queries, I see two options: 1. Data wrangling to create new data, 2. Use spark to get data from cassandra and then do all the operations https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector

Comment: What about https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-8473? I guess that's exactly what I'm looking for

Comment: I guess that would work but again you would need to create spec data in the map format. Also, remember to use collections type for smaller data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if this is the best answer. However after some researches I found [THIS](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-8473).

This way I can store Product's specs in a column with `MAP<TEXT, TEXT>` data type. Then create INDEX on it.

Then I can query it like the following :

`SELECT * FROM Products WHERE Specs['Ram'] > '3GB';`

Hence, the Ram is a Key in the MAP and 3GB is it's value.